# Valores eje Y a la derecha

Tags: chart.js, primeng

Estoy usando chartjs y primeng

```
<p-chart type="line" [data]="basicData[i]" [options]="options"></p-chart>
```

.ts

```
this.options = {
  plugins: {
      legend: {
          labels: {
              color: '#00008f'
          }
      }
  },
  scales: {
    position: 'right',
    y: {
       position: 'right',
    },
    yAxes: [{
      position: 'right',
   }]
  }
};
```

errores en consola

```
Invalid scale configuration for scale: position
```

Comment: Revisa la documentación de la migracion de chartjs v2 a v3, en este [enlace](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo similar a ésto

```
this.options = {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: { color: '#00008f'},
    legend: {position: 'right'},
    scales: {yAxes: [{bounds: 'ticks' }]}
  }
}
```

[Documentación](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/samples/line/line.html)

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar esto

```
this.option={

 scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057',
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef',
            },
          },
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057',
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef',
            },
          },
          y1: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            grid: {
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              color: '#ebedef',
            },
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057',
            },
          },
        },



}
```